# Jenkins Slave on local machine not launched

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins server on Ubuntu EC 2, i am trying to make a slave on my local windows machine, but not able to do. Even though i can make slaves on other EC 2 instances. is there some settings or some port need to be open. Jenkins is on ngnix.

Regards,
Ashish

Comment: Can you post some details of the problem you're having and what steps you took to set up the Windows slave ?

Comment: Created a jenkins node , launch method selected "Launch Slave agents via Java web start", Then downloaded slave-agent.jnlp, launched it, Nothing happened. Further i tried to give port 8080 as "Tunnel connection through" option in node configuration. Now it stopped at handshaking. Also please note that i have opened port 80, 8080, 443 in ec2 security groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a firewall rule to allow the port used by Jenkins for master-slave communication.  Go to $JENKINS_URL/configureSecurity and set the port to a fixed number that's available on your Jenkins master, then add a firewall rule for that port.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. used port 7777, i hope this would work for every slave.

Comment: Yes, if you use a fixed port, all slaves will use it.